# SharePoint 2013 People list separated linebreak instead of semicolon

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 with a Person or Group column. The column accepts multiple users, separated by a ;.

How can I display this list of users in the home site separated by a line break instead of a ;?

Comment: You will have to use the client side rendering (CSR) and JSLink to achieve this.

Comment: Could you show me an example?